# How to make LocationManager get very frequent location updates?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I'm currently using the requestLocationUpdates() method, which I am passing through the minimum time and minimum distance values. However, even if I make these values very small i.e 5ms and 0m, it still doesn't seem to be getting updated very frequently. I am using geofences in my application and I want it to register that the user has entered a geofenced area as soon as they enter it (needs to be sensitive).

```
 locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,5,0,locationListener);
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The GPS in your phone may simply not support updating the location that fast. Some googling suggests that 1 Hz is a common maximum update rate.

Comment: 1Hz would be fine but I'm sure it's less frequent than that. I've been out testing my app and sometimes I'll enter one of the geofenced areas and it won't trigger for up to 2 mins of me standing there. Maybe it's a problem with the geofences themselves? But unlikely because sometimes I'll get lucky and the location triggers them instanty.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were writing your own custom geofencing implementation since you were calling `requestLocationUpdates`. But yeah, a couple of minutes sounds about right for Google's geofencing API. It even says so [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing): _"Alerts can be late. The geofence service doesn't continuously query for location, so expect some latency when receiving alerts. Usually the latency is less than 2 minutes, even less when the device has been moving."_

Comment: (continued) _"If Background Location Limits are in effect, the latency is about 2-3 minutes on average. If the device has been stationary for a significant period of time, the latency may increase (up to 6 minutes)"_.